# For Test Scripts , Coded UI Option not available in Visual studio 2015

Tags: visualstudio, coded-ui-tests

I have tried installing VS2015 community edition and professional edition both. In the tutorials , there is a option for CodedUI available in Visual C# > Test .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have ***Visual Studio Enterprise Edition*** See 
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/ and [differences between Professional and Enterprise](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/03/16/6-differences-between-vs-2015-enterprise-and-pro/) versions